SendGid - Way to organize automations into folders?
Is there a way to organize automations that are created within SendGrid? Ideally within folders? As more automations get created it is increasingly difficult to find previous automations.
Tried using more descriptive titles / names for automations but still unwieldy. Organizing via folders is ideal path desired.
